# Store semicolon-separated integers into array after reading from file

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have my data from a text file that looks like this:

```
...
[timestamp]
1096757
[logtime]
2019-10-22 15:29:17.435
[scan]
32;39;36;39;39;39;39;42;42;44;46;48;48;49;51;52;54;54;54;53;50;50;50;54;54;56;56;56;56;57;57;56;56;58;56;56;57;58;58;59;58;59;60;61;60;61;61;60;60;61;61;62;63;63;63;63;63;61;61;61;61;61;61;62;62;62;62;62;62;64;68;64;64;63;61;61;61;60;61;60;62;60;60;59;60;59;59;57;62;57;57;57;57;57;58;63;63;63;63;63;61;61;62;59;59;61;62;61;63;64;63;61;63;61;61;61;63;63;63;59;62;62;59;60;60;60;57;60;61;61;61;61;61;61;56;56;56;57;59;61;61;59;57;57;57;57;59;61;59;61;60;60;60;63;63;63;63;63;63;61;61;61;62;62;62;62;65;69;69;68;68;70;68;72;72;72;71;72;72;73;72;73;73;73;73;73;73;73;73;72;71;69;69;69;69;70;73;70;68;68;68;66;65;66;66;64;64;64;62;60;57;57;57;53;53;53;51;50;47;46;45;44;44;44;44;43;42;43;43;44;45;45;45;45;
[timestamp]
1096858
[logtime]
2019-10-22 15:29:17.532
[scan]
41;38;38;38;38;38;40;40;41;42;46;47;49;49;48;49;50;49;51;52;52;52;52;53;53;53;57;58;58;58;58;57;57;57;56;56;59;56;57;58;58;58;58;58;61;63;59;60;61;60;60;61;61;61;61;61;61;62;62;60;60;60;60;60;60;61;61;61;62;63;63;62;62;62;62;64;65;65;64;59;59;59;60;60;61;61;60;63;63;62;59;58;58;58;59;61;61;62;64;64;64;63;63;60;60;63;64;64;64;63;63;60;58;58;58;59;59;59;59;59;59;59;61;60;60;60;60;60;60;60;60;61;61;59;59;58;58;59;62;62;62;59;59;59;59;59;61;61;61;61;61;60;60;62;62;62;62;62;62;62;62;64;64;66;66;69;69;70;69;69;70;71;71;72;72;72;72;72;73;74;74;71;71;71;70;71;71;71;71;72;72;76;72;71;70;71;70;71;70;66;65;65;64;63;64;60;60;60;
[timestamp]
...
```

I am trying to take the first 10 numbers from the data after the word `[scan]`.
I managed to make my code find the line number for the data, but I couldn't find a way to take the data (the first 10 of every scan) into an array of int.

I used some code that I found, but it didn't work as I expected.

I am trying to save the data to look like this. The first array contains:

```
32
39
36
39
39
39
39
42
42
44
```

The second array contains this:

```
41
38
38
38
38
38
40
40
41
42
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  So what do you have for code so far? We can more effectively help you if we know what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote in your question your are able to find the lines which contains desired data in your input file. So i assume you are able to read that line and store it as `std::string`. The following example shows how to extract the first 10 numbers from `std::string`separated by semicolon and add it to a `std::vector<int>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "32;39;36;39;39;39;39;42;42;44;46;48;48;49;51;52;54;";
    std::vector<int> token_list;
    std::string::size_type start_pos = 0;
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;

    while ((token_list.size() < 10) && ((pos = str.find(";", start_pos)) != std::string::npos))
    {
        token_list.push_back(std::stoi(str.substr(start_pos, pos - start_pos)));
        // Set next start position for search behind found semicolon
        start_pos = pos+1;
    }

    // Print extracted data
    for (size_t i = 0; i < token_list.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << token_list[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wow you guys are awesome. I tried your code through CodeBlocks but it didn't work. I got an error like this : #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be \
enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
#endif

#endif

Comment: It seems your compiler version is not up to date. I use gcc/g++ 8.3 which supports C++ standards 11,14 and 17 as well as a lot of features of next standard C++20. See https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html to get an overview which C++ standards and features are supported by which gcc/g++ version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split a string into substrings using a special pattern, then this is called tokenizing. This is a very old mechanism and even in C there was a function `strtok` to split a string into tokens.

In C++ there is also an algorithm available, especially in cooperation with container classes.

This is the so called `std::sregex_token_iterator`. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator). This iterates over a `std::string` and returns the tokens.

So, you have a specific and dedicated functionality that you should use.

The next dedicated function for copying n data from one container to another container is `std::copy_n`.

With that, the whole task will be done with a one liner.

Also transformation from the string-data to any number format can be done by the dedicated function `std::transfrom`.

And the output is also copied from the vector to `std::cout`.

Please see the below simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>

int main() {

    // The source values
    std::string source{ "32;39;36;39;39;39;39;42;42;44;46;48;48;49;51;52;54;" };

    // Here we will store the result
    std::vector<std::string> destination{}; // As string
    std::vector<int> data{};                // Int, or whatever else you want

    // This is the separator betwenn the numbers
    std::regex separator{ ";" };

    // One-liner to copy 10 sub strings to the destination array
    std::copy_n(std::sregex_token_iterator(source.begin(), source.end(), separator, -1), 10, std::back_inserter(destination));

    // Convert ot ints (or whatever)
    std::transform(destination.begin(), destination.end(), std::back_inserter(data), [](const std::string& s) { return std::stoi(s); });

    // And show result on std::cout
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Please note: You could of course directly copy the destination data to `std::cout`. The user will not see the difference on the screen. But if you want to do some further calculations, then you need the transformation.

And, also `std::transform` can directly write to `std::cout`. Like below:

```
    std::transform(destination.begin(), destination.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"), [](const std::string & s) { return std::stoi(s); });
```

Please notice the beauty of modern C++ algorithms. There is more to come with C++20.

Comment: Thank you so much. The code didn't wok though. I am using CodeBlocks and somehow it keep giving me an error : #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be \
enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
#endif

#endif